# R Markdown not producing bibliographies for PDF

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pdflatex, bibtex

I am about to give up on LaTex through Rmarkdown. I mean honestly what is the point when it is just a constant stream of errors that take an hour to solve. Anyway, the last thing that I *need* to solve is the bibliography. It does not appear, no matter what I do. I am not sure what esoteric knowledge is required to make this work but simply following instructions through Bookdown is apparently not enough. My header is set up like so:

```
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 3
    citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: zika.bib
```

And the final section I am outputting is as follows:

```
# References

nocite: |
  @*
```

When I do this, I get "References" in my table of contents in a weird location.
[image: References out of place in TOC]

And I also get the default references shown instead of the references in my bib as well as an additional references section with the @* parameter.
[image: references doubled]

I am trying to just cite all bib references for now as a test and I will add in a few more once I get that working. I will probably just cite all at the end instead of referencing throughout, although I tried in-text citations and they were not added to the references section at the end either. I have tried dozens of different ways of writing this out in the YAML header as well as changing the nocite call at the end. I often have the problem shown here, or no references and no errors or I commonly get an error saying that the bibliography cannot be built from either biblatex or biber. I'm not sure what causes one or the other as it seems to be random. I'm guessing that my .bib is somehow not being linked to the .rmd, but I'm not sure what I need to do to change this. I've tried relative and absolute paths, but this produces one of the issues I mention above. Does anyone know what I might be missing?

Comment: Have you tried `nocite: |  @your_ref1, @your_ref2` etc rather than `nocite: |   @*, ` with the line beginning with the `@` sign starting on a new line?

Comment: This removes the default references, but it doesn't change the essentially blank references section at the end. It now just says "nocite: Aguiareaay6736" instead of "nocite: @". The table of contents is still wrong as well.

Comment: It says that it should be a metadata field: `--- nocite: |  @* ---`. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/bibliography.html

Comment: Yes, I have entered that format as well, though I did realize that its not the same as I posted above. It doesn't solve my problem, just prints off a slightly different incorrect pdf. I think there must be some issue with linking my .bib file, but I can't figure out what. It is in the same folder as the .rmd file, however It doesn't seem to recognize it in any way.

Comment: Well I followed the above manual and it worked fine for me. I had a test bib file with only one entry.